# bash,how convert logger script to a function

Tags: linux, bash, logging, exec

I want to forward all my stdout and errout to a logger script that log them with some extra info such as dateTime and the script caused the error. After some googling I finally wrote my bash program in this manner:
I added these two lines in my main script:

```
exec  1> >(xargs ./doLog)
exec  2> >(xargs ./doLog)
```

The ./doLog is somehow like this:

```
if [ -n $1 ]
then
    echo -n "Jaky: `date`: $@ " >> $Log_File
fi
```

So it takes every input from 1> and 2> and echo it to my log file. 
The problem is that for some reason I need to convert the doLog script to a function that perform the same result. but I don't know how to pass the input of exec 1 and 2 to a function. I tried xargs and other file descriptor but I couldn't get the result.

Another problem is that the log passed to the doLog doesn't contain end of line character, So all output appear connected to each other. 
Some help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `xargs` for functions. That's why you need to read tha data in the function direct from stdin. Do it using `read`. There is a small example below.

Function:

```
dolog()
{
  while read log_entry
  do
   echo "Jaky: `date`: $log_entry " >> $Log_File 
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
your-command | dolog
```

Comment: You know, I cant pipe my main script to another. I need to main script be stand alone and doesn't need any extra script and piping for execution. 
by the way, do you mean your-command=mainScript ?

Comment: This function must be _inside_ your main script. It's not an external script or command.

Comment: And what to do with exec 1> and 2> .Should I remove them and pipe all my output to this function. Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: or how to redirect output of exec 2> to this function?

Comment: Please, place `>> $Log_File` after `done` in order, to reduce disk access !!

Comment: Use `date +"Jacky: %a %d %b %T:$log_entry"`, instead of `echo Jacky: $(date): $Log_entry` for better use and presentation (formatting)